# Derivation of range for a horizontal projectile?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

I know that if,
$$
s = ut + 0.5gt^2
$$
then displacement along $x$-axis is
$$
\begin{align}
x &= ut + 0.5 a_x t^2 \\
  &= u \sqrt{\frac{2h}{g}}+ \frac{1}{2}g \cdot \frac{2h}{g} \\
  &= R \\
  &= u \sqrt{\frac{2h}{g}}+h
\end{align}
$$

In my textbook it's given,$$
\text{Horizontal range}~~=~~R~~=~~u\sqrt{\frac{2h}{g}}
\,,$$
where $h$ is vertical displacement and $u$ is initial velocity.

**Question:** Why doesn't the final equation have $h$ in it?

Comment: The final formula assumes a flat planar surface. If the projectile was shot off a cliff that would be another consideration. Long range cannons have to make significant corrections for the curvature of the earth's surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book assumes that this event is taking place at the surface of earth. In such a scenario, only in vertical $y$ direction the projectile will be exerted upon by a force (gravitational  pull by the earth). And in direction along $x$ axis there will be no force acting hence no accelaration.

So the formula you have put for displacement along $x $is wrong. It would simply be
$$x=ut $$

Now you won't get the $h $ term.